# Difference between sexp and list in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp, delimiter, parentheses, s-expression

In Emacs there are commands to move cursor across expressions delimited in parentheses (or any brackets), namely forward-sexp, backward-sexp, forward-list and backward-list. In Lisp and any other code they behave similarly, so i see no difference between *-sexp and *-list except the last do not work inside comments or quotes.

What is the functional difference between sexp and list commands, and when should i use which?

Just in case, i understand the up-list and down-list commands, they are irrelevant to the topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A list is one example of an s-expression, so any function which operates on s-expressions should work on lists (but not necessarily vice-versa, as there are also non-list sexps).

The elisp manual says:

> A Lisp object that is intended for evaluation is called a "form" or
>   "expression"(1).  The fact that forms are data objects and not merely
>   text is one of the fundamental differences between Lisp-like languages
>   and typical programming languages.  Any object can be evaluated, but in
>   practice only numbers, symbols, lists and strings are evaluated very
>   often.
>
> ---------- Footnotes ----------
>
> (1) It is sometimes also referred to as an "S-expression" or "sexp",
>   but we generally do not use this terminology in this manual.

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Intro Eval` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Answer (score 6):

Not all s-expressions are lists, e.g. variables are s-expressions while they're obviously not lists.

Consider the following example:

```
foo (bar)
```

If you place the point at the beginning of the line, `forward-sexp` will move the point to the end of "foo" while `forward-list` will move the point to the end of "(bar)"